# Prototypal and Nonprototypal inheritance in Javascript (differences)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, inheritance, prototype

Time after time in different sources I see mentioning about Prototypal inheritance and Nonprototypal inheritance, but I dont understand what does it means. As I know JS have only [Prototypal inheritance](http://javascript.info/tutorial/inheritance) so what is another one?

What differences and what is the main idea?

Comment: You're true, there is no other inheritance than prototypal in JS.

Comment: Could you provide a link to *any* source that talk about "nonprototypal" inheritance in JavaScript?

Comment: The 'other' or 'nonprototypal' kind of inheritance is called 'classical' i.e. based on classes. It is not supported in JS (until ES2015 standard), but there are many ways to emulate it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I think there's no such thing as non-prototypal inheritance. The model of inheritance used in JS is prototypal inheritance, which is uses chains of prototypes.